# Laravel layout variable sharing

Tags: laravel, view, relationships

I have layout called app.blade.php

and in views I extends that layout.

How can I pass data from pivot table in master layout to be on every page.

Answer (score 2):

You can add [`View::share()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) to service provider to share data with all views:

```
public function boot()
{
    View::share('key', 'value');
}
```

Or you could create [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers).

> View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a view is rendered. If you have data that you want to be bound to a view each time that view is rendered, a view composer can help you organize that logic into a single location.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the variable into the blade `@extend` tag like this:

```
@extends(' <<Your file name>> ', ['value' => $value])
```